# Is there an easy way to turn ExtJS Time Picker into a time interval input?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I am trying to see if ExtJS6 [time picker](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Time.html) field can be easily adapted to accept any time interval, like 48 hours and 15 minutes (48:15:00). By default it accepts only time within 24hr range (which makes sense as it's backed by `Date()` object).

Comment: Can't you just make a combo box with a set of predefined options?

Comment: I agree with @EvanTrimboli, you should use a combo

Comment: @Mr.Bruno maybe my question wasn't clear. I need an input field `hh:mm:ss` where `hh` part can be over 24 hours. There is no place for a combo here, a user can enter any time interval they want.